# mySQL on JAVA exception : Column not found

Tags: java, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ITMc.png)

this is my database and

```
boolean login(String id, String pw) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "select * from login where id='" + id + "'";
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    haveID = isLogin(id);   //if ID in the Database
    rs.first();
    if (haveID) {
                System.out.println("Hello World");
                password = rs.getString("password");
                nickname = rs.getString("Nickname");

                System.out.println("password : " + password);
            if (password.equals(pw))
                login = true;
        }
        return login;
```

this is code but
`password = rs.getString("password")` doesn't work

Exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'password' not found.
```

but `'password'` column is in the Database.
what should I do?

Comment: Seeing that Nickname is capitalized, are you sure 'password' shouldn't be 'Password'?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ITMc.png Surely 'password'

Comment: what is `isLogin` doing?

Comment: isLogin() check if ID is in the database

Comment: how on earth is it doing that?

Comment: to check if ID is in the database, you must be working on the resultset right?

Comment: Also try `String sql = "select password, Nickname from login where id='" + id + "'";`

Comment: "select password, Nickname from login where id='" + id + "'"; same error..

Comment: OK, so again I ask, what are you doing in `isLogin` ?

Comment: 'boolean isLogin(String id) throws SQLException {
  boolean ok;
  String sql = "select count(*) from login where id=\"" + id + "\";";
  st = con.createStatement();
  rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
  rs.first();
  int row = rs.getInt("COUNT(*)");

  if (row == 0) {
   ok = false;
  } else
   ok = true;

  return ok;
 }'

Comment: well there you go, you are re-using `rs` from global scope.  This code is not even necessary as it is almost identical to the first sql isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
boolean login(String id, String pw) throws SQLException {
  String sql = "select * from login where id='" + id + "'";
  // keep scope local
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
  if (rs.next ())
  {
            System.out.println("has record");
            password = rs.getString("password");
            nickname = rs.getString("Nickname");

            //System.out.println("password : " + password);
            if (password.equals(pw)) {
              return true;
            }
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("no login record");
       return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Consider also to change to use a `PreparedStatement` in order to avoid SQL Injection

Answer (score -1):

You should make sure that `rs.first()` returns `true` before trying to get values from the `ResultSet`.

Example:

```
if (haveID && rs.first()) {
    password = rs.getString("password");
    nickname = rs.getString("Nickname");

    if (password.equals(pw)){
        login = true;
    }
}
```

I think the problem may be that you're changing the `rs` variable in your `isLogin(...)` method and because of that, the `ResultSet` no longer contains the results of your original query.

You can do something like this to prevent that:

```
boolean login(String id, String pw) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "select * from login where id='" + id + "'";
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    haveID = isLogin(id);   //if ID in the Database

    if (haveID && rs.first()) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        password = rs.getString("password");
        nickname = rs.getString("Nickname");

        System.out.println("password : " + password);
        if (password.equals(pw))
            login = true;
    }
    return login;
}
```

Comment: But you are still guessing.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yes, but this must be it, I can't see any other reason for the exception.

Comment: Yes, that is why I was asking for clafiication before you even posted your original answr